# joomla login email verification is not working!

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, email-validation

i have installed joomla 1.5 on a apache server with mysql in my windows server.the problem is when somebody try to register there is no email sent for the verification.
how can i setup that ?
how can i deactivate this verification function so that a user is enabled after registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.joomla.org/Allowing_user_registration